# How to display the correct view for this? Almost at the end of my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using this in my views to see that it's working, and, it is:

```
<%= post.comments if post.comments.present? %>
```

What that code does is pull the list of comments associated with a post.

It shows on my web page in this format:

```
[#<Comment id: 12, content: nil, user_id: 9, post_id: 18, created_at: "2013-03-12 04:51:47", updated_at: "2013-03-12 04:51:47", comment_content: "check">, #<Comment id: 13, content: nil, user_id: 9, post_id: 18, created_at: "2013-03-12 04:52:11", updated_at: "2013-03-12 04:52:11", comment_content: "check">]
```

I feel that I'm almost there with the backend code and I just need to correctly show the view.

How can I show just the Username and `comment_content` for a given post ID in a list format like a typical comment box? I already have it in ascending order using:

```
default_scope order: 'comments.created_at ASC'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to display the comment, user, and user's Gravatar, try the following:

```
<% if post.comments.exists? %>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <%= image_tag("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=#{Digest::MD5::hexdigest(comment.user.email)}", :alt => 'Avatar', :class => 'avatar') %> <!-- Retrieves Gravatar -->
        <%= comment.user.name %>
        <%= comment.comment_content %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This assumes that you have the user's email, and that the user has a Gravatar.

Comment: hey zeantsoi, when I tried <%= link_to(comment.user.name) %>.. all of the usernames link to the logged in current user. Do you know how I can make it link to the author of the comment?

Comment: If User has_many comments, and Comment belongs_to user, then `comment.user` should retrieve the user who the comment belongs to. Is it possible that the author of the comments in question is the currently logged in user?

Comment: kind of odd... I have User has_many comments as well as Comment belongs_to :user, but for some reason the username links to the current user. If a user named "John B" commented and I'm logged in as "Paul C", it links to Paul's user page.  Could this be caused by having Comment belongs_to :user AND Comment belongs_to :micropost in the model?

Comment: That is puzzling, but yes, it *might* be possible it has something to do with those other associations. I would suggest asking a separate question addressing that issue and including the all three models and the view in verbatim.

Comment: actually FYI, this seems to work <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user %>

Comment: Ahh, yes. The `link_to` tag in Rails works such that the first argument is the HTML displayed within the `<a>` tags, and the second is the path the link directs to. FYI, the `link_to` tag should **always** have at least have those two arguments, in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your user has a `name` attribute, you will have to loop through each comment like this:

```
<% if post.comments.exists? %>
  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    User: <%= comment.user.name %>
    Comment: <%= comment.comment_content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how I can also grab the gravatar of a user?

Comment: there's a gem that does this. https://github.com/sinisterchipmunk/gravatar you should look into it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if post.comments.present? %>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Content</th>
    </tr>
    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <tr>
       <td><%= comment.user.name %></td>
       <td><%= comment.comment_content %></td>
    </tr>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
```

This is used to show username and content for all comments in your view.

Comment: thank you, it works. what is the best way to break each user comments into separate rows? I usually use <br> but it doesn't help in this case and it's probably not the preferred way